# ClassLoader.getResources returns an empty Set

Tags: android, reflections

I am developing an Android application that uses the [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library to search for some annotated classes.

After some debugging hours spent trying to figure out why this library always returned empty sets to every query I did, I found out that the method [`getResources("foo/bar/")`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResources(java.lang.String)) of `ClassLoader` returns an empty Enumeration.

I used several ClassLoaders besides the one returned by `android.context.Context.getClassLoader()`, including `DexClassLoader` and `PathClassLoader`.

In the latter two, I input the APK saved at `/data/app`.

Comment: I've just faced with the same issue on android. Have you found any solution to this?